# 'Send membership requests to the following e-mail address' field in Sharepoint Group Creation Screen

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I had added one email in `Send membership requests to the following e-mail address` column, but no membership requests were sent to that email.

[image]

What is the format to provide the Email ID and how to provide multiple Email IDs in that field (for example, what is the separator ',' or ';'?).

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a tricky question, as it could be an exchange issue. Do all of your users have Licenses that offer mailboxes? Have you tried sending a test email to the account? Is the account that you are sending the email the actual group owner?

Comment: @jimas13 It tried with proving group owner email and other users email, every user has mailbox and mail were sending and receiving successfully between those users.

One more query, even if I give some text other than the email address in Send membership requests to the following e-mail address, it accepts the input